# Why do I get an error "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)" for a search query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This line raises the error "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)". I would really like to know how to get this query to work. Thanks!

```
@posts = Post.all(:joins => :course, :conditions => "course.name in (#{@user.courses.map(&:name).join(',')})",:order => "posts.created_at DESC")
```

This is code in my controller:

```
@user = current_user
@posts = Post.all(:joins => :course, :conditions => "course.name in (#{@user.courses.map(&:name).join(',')})",:order => "posts.created_at DESC")
```

Here are the models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :course
has_many :comments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :posts
belongs_to :major
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :courses
belongs_to :major
has_many :posts
has_many :comments

accepts_nested_attributes_for :courses, reject_if: :all_blank,      allow_destroy: true
end
```

And here is the schema

```
 create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.text     "comment"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "post_id"
end

add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"
add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "major_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "courses", ["major_id"], name: "index_courses_on_major_id"
add_index "courses", ["user_id"], name: "index_courses_on_user_id"

create_table "majors", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "content"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "course_id"
end

add_index "posts", ["course_id"], name: "index_posts_on_course_id"
add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
t.boolean  "admin"
t.string   "username"
t.integer  "major_id"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["major_id"], name: "index_users_on_major_id"
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true

 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting in the query is due to the fact that the [all](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dc925119a3912ecfe0df400007163f33b99d6385/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L24) method does not expect any parameters, it just retrieves all records for a given model/relation.

What you want to use in this case is the [where](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96f3f3d8267167d5d4c5697f2299756cfa7e37d4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L619) method from ActiveRecord::QueryMethods.

There is another error, you are using the name of the table in singular on your condition, where it should be plural (courses instead of course).

Also, you could use here the [includes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96f3f3d8267167d5d4c5697f2299756cfa7e37d4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L166) method combined with the [references](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96f3f3d8267167d5d4c5697f2299756cfa7e37d4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L219) method to generate the database join.

So, you would have something like the following:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:course).where("courses.name IN (#{@user.courses.map(&:name).collect { |s| '#{s}'  }.join(',') })").references(:courses).order("posts.created_at DESC")
```

Comment: This took the error away from the query, which is great! But I do now have an error on "@posts.each do" that says "Association named 'courses' was not found on Post;"

Comment: This is problem with the association name used in includes (in references it is correct, since this method expects the table name!), it should be course instead of courses, since it is a one-to-many (one course to many posts) relationship. I have fixed the typo. Also, I could not verify the query in its entirety yet, as I'm on mobile.

Comment: There is this error:  SQLite3::SQLException: near "Networks": syntax error: SELECT "posts"."id" AS t0_r0, "posts"."title" AS t0_r1, "posts"."content" AS t0_r2, "posts"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "posts"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "posts"."user_id" AS t0_r5, "posts"."course_id" AS t0_r6, "courses"."id" AS t1_r0, "courses"."name" AS t1_r1, "courses"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "courses"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "courses"."major_id" AS t1_r4, "courses"."user_id" AS t1_r5 FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "posts"."course_id" WHERE (courses.name IN (Electrical Networks,Physics 3))

Comment: The strings are not properly formatted to SQL, so you have to append a method to surround each course name with quotes. I'll add that to the answer as well.

Comment: Thank you, there is an error now though that says: undefined method `collect' for "Electrical Networks,Physics 3":String

Comment: Sorry, the chaining order was incorrect. Applying collect on String (after join) would not work, only on an Enumerable (Array).

Comment: The new error is: SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "#": SELECT "posts"."id" AS t0_r0, "posts"."title" AS t0_r1, "posts"."content" AS t0_r2, "posts"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "posts"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "posts"."user_id" AS t0_r5, "posts"."course_id" AS t0_r6, "courses"."id" AS t1_r0, "courses"."name" AS t1_r1, "courses"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "courses"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "courses"."major_id" AS t1_r4, "courses"."user_id" AS t1_r5 FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."id" = "posts"."course_id" WHERE (courses.name IN (#{s},#{s}))  ORDER BY posts.created_at DESC